# Should I set Back-End for my React Native application?

Tags: react-native, mobile-application

I'm building my first React-Native app that I would like to monetize.
The app will expect users' input. This input will be used as a parameter for API calls to ChatGPT.
Short app configuration description:

- make API calls to ChatGPT and store the response (in DB)
- Display stored data
- Sign in/Sign Up

I come from the web-development world so I'm not familiar with the best practices in mobile app development. My goal is to roll out something simple with minimum costs but still usable in the first stage. So I need to find a balance. I expect about 50-100 users per day in the beginning, having maybe not more than 300 API calls to ChatGPT.

In my ideal world, I would use the following architecture:

- React Native
- FastApi for backend
- DynamoDb for storing data (or something similar)
- AWS for running the backend

Questions:

- Is it mandatory to have a backend for such kind of app or everything can be handled from the front end part?
- Will it be fast enough and operational?
- What would you recommend?

Comment: You'll need some kind of api keys for the database and openapi, I assume. You'll not want those to be distributed from just the front end

Comment: unless your users talk directly to chatGpt youll need a backend

Comment: What would you use for the Backend? Does my plan sound reasonable at all?